# How to handle multiple request coming at the same time php

Tags: php

I have configured a url to other platform which is webhook for them. In this URL, order are coming simultaneously, which i manipulate and save it to the database.
The problem is that sometimes order timings are exactly same, so the orders data are mixed with each other and wrong information is saving into the database.
How would i handle this situation in php as i am using core php.

So that when two or more request are coming together, so each will be executed one by one.

For reading the input data sent to the url is

```
file_get_contents('php://input');
```

PHP CODE :

case "order_relay":

```
  $body = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $data = (array) json_decode($body);

  $orderData = (array) $data['order']->details;
```

break;

Comment: Depends which DB you are using - it should lock the table on its own to protect from problem you have. If your DB does not handle locking on its own, lock table for each  request until it is done so requests will get into the queue.

Comment: I would see this as a database issue rather than a php issue. You will want to take a look into locking your tables. This will prevent multiple read/writes happening while the table is locked.

Comment: i am using mysql and i am not using any locks in the table. Okay i will try to use the locks in the table. Thanks for help

Comment: what if i use transaction to solve this problem. would it work?

Comment: It's a bit unclear without seeing a proper example, but it sounds like you are using the timestamp of an item, or possibly even just the sequence it arrives in, to relate it back to some other data in your application? If so, then clearly that's not going to be reliable? Don't you have some kind of unique ID field for this data which can be used to associate the records to each other? I don't know...maybe I have missed the point. As I said, to get a clearer answer, give a clearer example